# I have an incorrect value of parameter id in a Hook of TYPO3 7.6

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to use a Hook for change values inserted by create record in Backend of TYPO3. For this I need to change value in database, so I should have the id. I am using `function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray ($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$reference){....}` but the `$id` doesn't have a common value (43, 67, 87, ...) the value is `NEW589ce2522e406137033561` and the value after the word `NEW` changes in each test. I do not understand why it assign this value.

I am using TYPO3 7.6 with PHP 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you create new record and it is its temporary unique id. If you want to get numeric value you can try to use this code. I use it for example in the `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations` hook

```
$internalId = $id;

if (strpos($id, 'NEW') !== false) {
    $internalId = $reference->substNEWwithIDs[$id];
}
```

After that check if `$internalId` contains id which you want

Comment: Thank you! I understand more the functionality of Hooks